# Git Bash doesn't recognize java command

Tags: git, git-bash

I know people have asked this question before, but I couldn't find / understand any information relevant to my situation.  I tried running "env|grep PATH" and it came out with this information:

/c/Users/J.D/bin:.:/usr/local/bin:/mingw/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Program Files
 (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/c/Program Files(x86)/AMD APP/bin/x86_64:/c/Program Files (x86)/AMD APP/bin/x86:/c/Program Files/Java/jre6/bin:/c/Program Files (x86)/ATI Technologies/ATI.ACE/Core-Static:/C/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_21/bin/

When I tried to follow this is got as far as /c/Users/J.D/ but then couldn't locate a bin file to proceed in.

The command I am trying to run is: "java -jar BuildTools.jar"
The error message I receive is: "sh: java: command not found"

Any information on how to rectify this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is in `/c/Program Files/Java/jre6/bin`? I would expect `java` executable there.

Comment: I've gone into /c/Program Files (x86)/java/jre7/bin and found a java executable, do I need to path Git Bash into that file?

Comment: That's maybe the problem - you have found java executable in jre7, but in yout PATH env variable is just jre6. Please add jre7 (`/c/Program Files (x86)/java/jre7/bin`) to PATH somehow. Or use full path to java executable (`"/c/Program Files (x86)/java/jre7/bin/java" -jar BuildToos.jar`).

Comment: Sorry I've been so slow to respond Messa and thank you for the help!  I ran the executable and it worked.  This has been a hair pulling issue for about a week now, thank you very much! I see there is a reputation on your profile, is there any way I an add the that reputation?